# dojo Layout is not working

Tags: layout, dojo

Can somebody post a dojo Layout working example. I have the below html file , Layout is not appearing at-all, I have all dojo related files in the root of the web app.[I even tried using google CDN , but no help]
the page contents are displayed without the Layout. 
I have copy pasted the example available in the Internet, but no success.
would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo: Layout with Dijit</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";

@import "dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css";

@import "dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/claro.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: false ,  isDebug: true"></script>

<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div>
                <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
                <p>para 1</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>h4 para 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>h4 para 3</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
        <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar
            content (left)</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have set parseOnLoad: false, and it doesn't look like you're calling the parser manually. Is that the case?

Comment: have you looked here? http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your reply, first I placed parseOnLoad: ture, it was not working, then I tried parseOnLoad: false , both are not working. I took the example from the above link only

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you have dojo parse your doc (see Frode's comment).

Also, you may need to give your body an explicit width and height (iirc, IE will collapse it otherwise).

Comment: your truly a master of dojo. after reading your reply, I have placed CSS for body height and width, it solved.

Comment: Glad that helped!  Don't forget to check the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo: Layout with Dijit</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" > 

<style type="text/css">
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0; 
} 

#appLayout { 
    height: 100%; 
} 
#leftCol { 
    width: 14em; 
}
</style>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"     
    data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>  

<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div>
                <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
                <p>para 1</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>h4 para 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>h4 para 3</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
        <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar
            content (left)</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

above code bringing the Layout. Thanks all who have helped.